# TypeScript - defining the data model with optional properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm pretty new to TypeScript. I would like to have a Table, that can have a group ***or*** rows property defined.

Already added the interfaces for the data model:

```ts
type GroupModel = {
  id: UUID
  name: string
  rows: RowModel[]
}

interface Table {
  readonly header: HeaderModel[]
  readonly pageIndex?: number
  readonly pageSize?: number
}

interface TableWithGroups {
  readonly groups: GroupModel[]
}

interface TableWithRows {
  readonly rows: RowModel[]
}


export type TableModel = Table & (TableWithRows | TableWithGroups)
```

but when it comes to the table component, I'm not sure how to specify that I would like to have TableWithRows in one case, and TableWithGroups in another.

I get an error when trying to spread the values from the data object, which is totally fine because TableModel might not have one of them.

```ts
const Table = ({ data }: Props) => {

const { rows, groups } = data
// Property 'rows' does not exist on type 'TableModel'
// Property 'groups' does not exist on type 'TableModel'

}
```

How should I specify that I want explicitly one of the table types? Is this achievable by making TableModel generic?

What's the best practice for having one of the values required?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this - with a union:

```
interface TableWithOption {
  optionType: GroupModel[] | RowModel[]
}
```

Comment: wouldn't it give me the additional ts errors in using the optionType?

e.g.:

`optionType.rows.map(mapFn) // property 'rows' does not exist on RowModel` ?

with this approach, I should explicitly specify which optionType I'm using in the table. 
do you think the generic approach would help me to avoid that? `Table<TableWithRows> or Table<TableWithGroups>? `

Comment: maybe some type guards would be helpful? pretty new to that and not sure how to make it work